# Can You Hack a Websites Server?

Tags: dom, dom-manipulation

I had an idea about website vulnerabilities, and I would like to know if it is possible. Also some suggestions on how to fix them.

If some part of my website writes data to the DOM and then calls the data back from it, would it be possible for someone to “hack” the server by editing the DOM in the browser?

For example, suppose I have some radio buttons. Each button has its own logic associated with it. If I remove one of the buttons, but fail to remove or comment out the logic, could someone go in and edit the DOM name of one of the buttons to the removed one, and upon submission have the server execute the logic associated with the removed radio button?

I understand how to fix that situation, by removing or commenting out the removed button’s logic, but I fear my site relies too heavily on such things that could be manipulated via the DOM. Hence, I’m wondering:

1. Is such a thing possible?
2. Is some complex validation method the only way to prevent “hacks” of this nature?

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand. What 'logic' are you talking about here? Does the client directly control what is executed on the server, with no validation or authentication? Are we talking Javascript or server-side code?

Comment: It's PHP coded logic. There is validation on certain things, but in some cases, like a radio button, there really isn't. I'm really just wondering if such "hacking" by DOM manipulation is possible and if it's something I should invest time in trying to prevent (since if it isn't possible, I don't see why I should waste the time then)

Comment: Sure. "Hacking" is always a risk. Without more detailed info, not much more of an answer can come, though. Hogan's answer might be helpful.

Comment: Alright, more detailed, let's see... `<input id="d" class="checkbox" type="radio" value="D" name="a"></input>
<input id="s" class="checkbox" type="radio" value="S" name="a"></input>` Two radio buttons. Now, if I remove value "S" radio button, but fail to remove the logic associated with it, or validate the form to not accept "S" as a valid value, could someone edit the DOM, change it to "S" and then run the logic associated with "S"? I'm taking that is possible and I should code with that in mind?

Comment: As I said in my answer not only could they edit the DOM like S is there, they could construct a server request with a value for S if your server side code does not validate -- even without the local code or DOM edit your website or web service is at risk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is yes.  For example in many browsers you can open a javascript console and change not only the DOM but also the javascript on the site.

There is no guarantee that the code you write for a webpage will be run as you code it.  Any user can change their copy.  What they should not be able to do is change other people's copy.  When they do this is called a cross site scripting (XSS) attack.  (Typically done by adding script to a field which is saved in a database server and then served to another user.)

To protect your site you need to ensure that all web service calls are secure -- that is a user can't call them with malicious data and cause problems.

You also need to block against SQL injection attacks.

There is NO way to protect against a user changing the web page on their machine and having it do something you did not intend, so all validation needs to occur both in the browser and on the server.

---

As an example of how easy it is to change the local browser behavior, consider the browser extension.  A browser extension is a pre-coded way to change the way web pages act locally.
(Think about ad-blockers as a specific example.)

Comment: Just to add to this... You can even forget all about people bothering with anything in the browser.  There is no need to bother with that when usually the web service calls are wide open and exploitable via a simple cURL.  Never trust anything from the user.